# How can I avoid hard coding the handlers for each menu item?

Tags: applescript, foundation

I have a stay open AppleScript app that creates a menu with many menu items. The handlers that is mapped are repetitive and only differs in its index. How can I refactor this code to dry it up?

```
on makeMenus(selectedIndex as integer)
    newMenu's removeAllItems() -- remove existing menu items

    set menuItems to {"POC1", "POC2"}

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in menuItems
        set this_item to item i of menuItems
        if i is equal to selectedIndex then set this_item to this_item & " " & (emoji's CHECK)
        set thisMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's alloc()'s initWithTitle:this_item action:("someAction" & (i as text) & ":") keyEquivalent:"")
        (newMenu's addItem:thisMenuItem)
        (thisMenuItem's setTarget:me)
    end repeat

    -- Create the Quit menu item separately
    set thisMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"Quit" action:("quitAction:") keyEquivalent:"")
    (newMenu's addItem:thisMenuItem)
    (thisMenuItem's setTarget:me)
end makeMenus
```

The repetitive handler is:

```
on someAction1:sender
    updateStatus(1)
end someAction1:

on someAction2:sender
    updateStatus(2)
end someAction2:
```

If I can derive the menu item name or index from a parameter in the `someAction` handler, that would let me have a single handler to take care of all the menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` argument of an action handler will be the object that called the action.  In this case the sender will be the particular `menuItem`, so a common action handler can use a property such as the sender's title.

Note that since it will be a Cocoa object, you will need to coerce the title to an AppleScript string, for example:

```
on doAction:sender
    set menuTitle to (sender's title) as text
    if menuTitle is "this" then
        doThis()
    else if menuTitle is "that" then
        doThat()
    else
        doOther()
    end if
end doAction:
```